# Can SSRS reports be integrated into the free version of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

Do I have to upgrade to another edition of SharePoint to integrate SSRS reports or is SharePoint integrated mode with SSRS available with the free version of SharePoint (Sharepoint Services 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS works fine in SharePoint Integrated Mode on WSS3, but you'll need to remember to install the Reporting Services Add In for the appropriate version of SQL Server you have installed.